# Python-GroupBy one column and perform transitive closure on another column from the resultant dataframe

Tags: python, group-by

I have a dataframe ('Occurences') like this:

```
      GlobalEventId      EventTimeDate        MentionIdentifier
0     4267153839         2.015100e+13          http://www.indystar.com/story/news/politics/2015

1     4712938798        2.015100e+13          http://www.indystar.com/story/news/politics/20...

2     4513293479        2.015100e+13 htp://www.thezimbabwedaily.com/zimbabwe/38299
```

I have another dataframe('Events') which contains:

```
      GlobalEventId        SQLDate           EventRootCode
0    4712938798            20151001                18

1    4153591279            20151001                09

2    4267153839            20151001                11
```

What I need to do: I need to 'groupby' MentionIdentifier from the 'Occurences' dataframe so that we we will know which EventIds occur in the **same** URL (MentionIdentifier). For example, in the sample data above, both events '4267153839' and '4712938798' occur in the same source URL/MentionIdentifier. I then need to perform transitive closure of that relation as a notion of relevance between events: relevant(e,e’) holds if we have some sequence of events  such that e=e1, e’=en and for each i in {1,…n}, we have co-mentions(ei, ei+1).

How do I achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `Pandas`'s dataframe?

Comment: Yes. I am using Pandas! :)  We have a 'groupby' function but I am confused on how to extract the 'EventRootCode's pertaining to each URL and then perform a transitive closure?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Pandas module. We have a 'groupby' function but I am confused on how to extract 'EventRootCodes's pertaiing to each URL/MentionIdentifier and then perform a transitive closure. I am quite a newbie to Python!

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the documentation. Thankyou. But, I need to perform a transitive closure on the extracted results!

Comment: For each grouped sequences of `eventID`, sort and partition it into consecutive sets. Store these sets into a list and record the membership in a dictionary. Now you can use `dictionary[eid]` to get `[2, 100, 2000]`, which refers to the sequences at corresponding indices in the list

Comment: Please explain with an example.

Comment: Please provide with your attempts before I hand you the code. I am trying to help without being a horse. Or you can wait until someone else willingly become your code horse.